# Quartz Scheduler task suddenly not running

Tags: java, spring, quartz

Task has started,but nerver executed ,Anyone know what's problem there?
Now the Problem is every time i run the code it gives me only The output

Here's the final log

```
2020-11-02 17:03:30.852 DEBUG 9264 --- [nio-8089-exec-7] c.z.t.c.quartz.QuartzScheduleManager     : addNewCronJob() called with: jobInfo = [JobInfo(className=class com.zx.tzgl.cronJob.YearPlanJob, identifier=25ddaab4-3e3b-45e9-84a3-77ff7ca4c049, groupName=zx, cornExpr=00 18 17 02 11 ? 2020, params={PLAY_YEAR_SWITCH_PARAMS={"planType":"1","isOpen":"1","enable":"1","annual":"2020至2025","closeTime":1604307810844,"id":"1"}})]
2020-11-02 17:03:30.852  INFO 9264 --- [nio-8089-exec-7] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler SchedulerFactory_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
```

Here's my using quartz' version

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Here's the quartz.properties file content

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = DefaultQuartzScheduler


org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false

org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false

org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction = false

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool


org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 100

org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5

org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true


org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 5000

#org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX

org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate


org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=true

org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_

org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myQuartzDB




org.quartz.dataSource.myQuartzDB.driver:oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
#org.quartz.dataSource.myQuartzDB.URL:jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/cdb1
#org.quartz.dataSource.myQuartzDB.user:xxxx
#org.quartz.dataSource.myQuartzDB.password:xxxx
org.quartz.dataSource.myQuartzDB.URL:jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xx.xx.x.xx:xxxx/szorcl
org.quartz.dataSource.myQuartzDB.user:xxxx
org.quartz.dataSource.myQuartzDB.password:xxxx
org.quartz.dataSource.myQuartzDB.maxConnections:10

org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=false
```

Here's Configuartion

```
@Configuration
public class QuartzConfig {
    @Resource
    private MyJobFactory myJobFactory;

    @Bean(name = "SchedulerFactory")
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() throws IOException {
        SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        factory.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties());
        factory.setJobFactory(myJobFactory);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties quartzProperties() throws IOException {
        PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("config/quartz.properties"));
        propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

  
    @Bean
    public QuartzInitializerListener executorListener() {
        return new QuartzInitializerListener();
    }

    @Bean(name = "quartzScheduler")
    public Scheduler scheduler() throws IOException {
        return schedulerFactoryBean().getScheduler();
    }

}

@Component
public class MyJobFactory extends AdaptableJobFactory {
    @Autowired
    private AutowireCapableBeanFactory capableBeanFactory;

    @Override
    protected Object createJobInstance(TriggerFiredBundle bundle) throws Exception {
        Object jobInstance = super.createJobInstance(bundle);
        capableBeanFactory.autowireBean(jobInstance);
        return jobInstance;
    }
}
```

Here's the schduler manager

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class QuartzScheduleManager implements QuartzScheduleI {


    @Resource(name = "quartzScheduler")
    private Scheduler scheduler;

    @Override @SneakyThrows
    public void checkAndAddCornJob(JobInfo jobInfo) {
        if (isExistJob(jobInfo)) {
            resumeJob(jobInfo);
        } else {
            addNewCronJob(jobInfo);
        }
    }

    @Override @SneakyThrows
    public boolean isExistJob(JobInfo jobInfo) {
        return scheduler.checkExists(new JobKey(jobInfo.getIdentifier(), jobInfo.getGroupName()));
    }

    @Override @SneakyThrows
    public boolean isExistJob2(JobInfo jobInfo) {
        boolean isExist = false;
        JobKey jobKey1 = new JobKey(jobInfo.getIdentifier(), jobInfo.getGroupName());
        List<? extends Trigger> triggers1 = scheduler.getTriggersOfJob(jobKey1);
        if (triggers1.size() > 0) {
            for (Trigger tg : triggers1) {
                if ((tg instanceof CronTrigger) || (tg instanceof SimpleTrigger)) {
                    isExist = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return isExist;
    }


   
    private void addNewCronJob(JobInfo jobInfo) throws Exception {
        scheduler.start();

        //build job info
        JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(jobInfo.getClassName()).
                withIdentity(jobInfo.getIdentifier(), jobInfo.getGroupName())
                .build();
        //add params to job
        if (ObjectUtil.isNotNull(jobInfo.getParams()) && !jobInfo.getParams().isEmpty()) {
            jobInfo.getParams().forEach((key, value) -> jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put(key, value));
        }

        CronScheduleBuilder scheduleBuilder = CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(jobInfo.getCornExpr());
        CronTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().
                withIdentity(jobInfo.getIdentifier(), jobInfo.getGroupName())
                .forJob(jobDetail)
                .withSchedule(scheduleBuilder)
                .build();

        try {
            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);

        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            throw new CustomException(ResultCode.PARAM_ERROR.getCode(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Here's the job listener

```
public class YearPlanJob implements Job {

    @Override public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) {
        JobDetail jobDetail = jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail();

        JobDataMap jobDataMap;
        if (!jobDetail.getJobDataMap().isEmpty()) {
            jobDataMap = jobDetail.getJobDataMap();
        } else {
            jobDataMap = jobExecutionContext.getTrigger().getJobDataMap();
        }


    }
}
```

Here's my test code

```
    public String testQuartzTask() {
        Date date = DateUtil.parse("2020-11-02 17:18:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        PlanapplyYear planapplyYear = new PlanapplyYear();
        planapplyYear.setCloseTime(new Date());
        String jsonParams = JSONUtil.toJsonStr(planapplyYear);
        JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo();
        jobInfo.setClassName(YearPlanJob.class);
        jobInfo.setIdentifier(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        jobInfo.setGroupName("zx");
        jobInfo.setCornExpr(CronDateUtils.getCron(date));
        jobInfo.setParams(ImmutableMap.of(PLAN_YEAR_SWITCH, jsonParams));

        mQuartzScheduleManager.checkAndAddCornJob(jobInfo);
        
    }
```

Comment: Did the task appear in `quartz_` tables in DB?

Comment: Yes,but that would take a while when this task actually  exists on the database,I don't know what's this problem too.Does that the task would not executed if the task not store the db table?Isn't that this task would be store the memory first ?

Comment: Task is stored in memory when you choose `org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore`. You've chosen `jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX` hence tasks are stored in DB